# Getting this Error message when i added GSCFuse and deployed my application in Kubernetes Any Suggestions what could be the issue

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gcsfuse

poststarthookerror: **command 'gcsfuse -o nonempty config_files_1_bucket /home/test123/' exited with 126**
I am adding the gcs fuse command in my yaml file like

lifecycle:

```
      postStart:
        exec:
          command:
          - gcsfuse
          - -o
          - nonempty
          - config_files_1_bucket
          - /home/test123
      preStop:
        exec:
          command:
          - fusermount
          - -u
          - /home/test123
```

Answer (score 1):

same here. It used to work (on gcsfuse version 0.28.1) but i does not anymore (0.32.0). The fact is that they removed support of the nonempty option (https://github.com/appsembler/roles/pull/85) because it is not more supported in fusermount v3.0
Simply remove the nonempty option and it should work.

More here : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/424